# Mysql forward engineered sql duplicate foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-8.0

i don't know much SQLs, i generated this using modelling via MySQL Workbench. I always get a `Error Code: 1826. Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'post_id'` when i try to import the SQL generated via Forward Engineering of workbench. If anybody could me out. I am not coding this from scratch. I just made a ERD and generated an SQL.

Additional info, the error fires in this line

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`post_likes` ...

Also, MySQL Workbench and Server are both version 8.0.19

Here is the generated SQL

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Tue Mar 31 21:51:19 2020
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema testing
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema testing
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `testing` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `testing` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`users` (
  `userid` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `handle` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `quote` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `last_updated` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`posts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`posts` (
  `post_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `user_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `images` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `tags` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `last_updated` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`users` (`userid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`comments` (
  `comment_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `post_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `images` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `last_updated` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  INDEX `post_id_idx` (`post_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `post_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`posts` (`post_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`post_likes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`post_likes` (
  `plike_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `post_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `user_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`plike_id`),
  INDEX `post_id_idx` (`post_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `post_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`posts` (`post_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`users` (`userid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testing`.`comment_likes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing`.`comment_likes` (
  `clike_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `user_id` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clike_id`),
  INDEX `comment_id_idx` (`comment_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `comment_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`comments` (`comment_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `testing`.`users` (`userid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: I suggest visible indexes are available in your ui but not in your version of mysql. If you are using mysqlworkbench turn off this behaviour (see mysqlworkbench manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html)

Comment: do you mean unticking "Visible" checkbox?

Comment: did it but the same error occurs

Comment: Then I guess you have to manually edit the .sql file

Comment: do you mean remove sa "VISIBLE" part?

Comment: Just remove anything that says visible.

Comment: ohh i see, i just removed only the affected create table part. Just removed everything that says `VISIBLE` but still the error occurs. by the way, i forgot to mention the versions. My workbench is 8.0.19 and my server is mysql 8.0.19. updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210673/discussion-between-p-salmon-and-lemoncodes).

Comment: Indexes are visible by default. Remove that and as suggested you had double names in FK. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pA2Av6pvMy7ZmtBMQVFoj8/0

Comment: Also just a warning. You are using in users table userid as primary. And later you are using user_id, this might give you headache later when creating query's.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per discussion with @P.Salmon, it was indicated that the FK name was duplicated. So i adjusted the FK name via the ERD ang generated a new SQL file. So basically, i adjusted avoid using the same FK name and voila, it works.

See below

[image]